# Moving cube in opengl on android help

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, cube

After a lot of trial and error I was able to draw a cube and a tile map for the cube to be infront of.  I added input so that when you move your finger, the camera moves.  But now I want to add the next step in my games progression.  I want it to have my cube move to where i pressed my finger in 3d space.  It sounds a bit difficult. What I wanted to do is have you use one finger to slide the camera around the map and the other to double tap and move.  So far my cube jitters and wobbles in place but doesn't move to where I want it to go.  Of course none of my code is perfect and my following of gluunproject might be far from correct.  Here is my code so far

The cube creator and update code//its short

```
public shapemaker(int x, int y, int z,int width)
{
    centerx =x;
    centery =y;
    centerz =z;



        mysquare1= new square(centerx,centery,centerz-5,1,.0f,.0f,1f,"vert");
        mysquare2= new square(centerx-1,centery,centerz-6f,1,.0f,1.0f,.0f,"side");
        mysquare3= new square(centerx,centery,centerz-7,1,1.0f,.0f,.0f,"vert");
        mysquare4= new square(centerx+1,centery,centerz-6f,1,.0f,.5f,.5f,"side");
        mysquare5= new square(centerx,centery-1,centerz-6f,1,.5f,.5f,.0f,"horiz");
        mysquare6= new square(centerx,centery+1,centerz-6f,1,.5f,.0f,.5f,"horiz");
}

public void updatecube(float x, float y, float z)
{


        centerx =x;
        centery =y;
        centerz =z;

        mysquare1= new square(centerx,centery,centerz-5,1,.0f,.0f,1f,"vert");
        mysquare2= new square(centerx-1,centery,centerz-6f,1,.0f,1.0f,.0f,"side");
        mysquare3= new square(centerx,centery,centerz-7,1,1.0f,.0f,.0f,"vert");
        mysquare4= new square(centerx+1,centery,centerz-6f,1,.0f,.5f,.5f,"side");
        mysquare5= new square(centerx,centery-1,centerz-6f,1,.5f,.5f,.0f,"horiz");
        mysquare6= new square(centerx,centery+1,centerz-6f,1,.5f,.0f,.5f,"horiz");
}

public void drawcube(GL10 gl)
{
    mysquare1.draw(gl);        
    mysquare2.draw(gl);        
    mysquare3.draw(gl);        
    mysquare4.draw(gl);        
    mysquare5.draw(gl);        
    mysquare6.draw(gl);

}
public float getcenterx()
{
    return centerx;
}
public float getcentery()
{
    return centery;
}
public float getcenterz()
{
    return centerz;
}
```

Here is the actual implementation code , it is based off of googles intro to opengl

```
class ClearGLSurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView {
    private static final String BufferUtils = null;
    float x =0;
    float y =0;
    float z =0f;
    float prevx=0;
    float prevy=0;
    GL10 mygl;
   // GL gl;
    float mywidth;
    float myheight;








public ClearGLSurfaceView(Context context,float width, float height) {
    super(context);
    mRenderer = new ClearRenderer();
    setRenderer(mRenderer);
    mywidth = width;
    myheight = height;





}
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(final MotionEvent event)
{

    queueEvent(new Runnable() {
        // Find the index of the active pointer and fetch its position
        public void run()
        {
            float curx = event.getX();
            float cury = event.getY();
            final int action = event.getAction();
            if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
            {


            if(curx>prevx)
            {
                  x-=.1f;
            }
            if(curx<prevx)
            {
                  x+=.1f;
            }
            if(cury>prevy)
            {
                  y+=.1f;
            }
            if(cury<prevy)
            {
                  y-=.1f;
            }



            }
            if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            {
                // GLU.gluUnProject(winX, winY, winZ, model,
                //       modelOffset, project, projectOffset, view, viewOffset, obj, objOffset)
                vector2d moveto = new vector2d(0,0);
                moveto = mRenderer.getworkcoords(curx,cury);
                Log.i("move to ", "x "+moveto.x+" y "+ moveto.y+" z " + moveto.z);
                mRenderer.updatemoveto(moveto.x, moveto.y);



            }
            prevx= curx;
            prevy = cury;

            mRenderer.updatecamera(x, y, z);
}
 });
    return true;
} 

    ClearRenderer mRenderer;
```

}

class ClearRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {

```
       GL10 mygl;
       GL11 mygl11;

       int viewport[] = new int[4];
        float modelview[] = new float[16];
        float projection[] = new float[16];
        float wcoord[] = new float[4];

public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {

    gl.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f);  // OpenGL docs.
    gl.glShadeModel(GL10.GL_SMOOTH);// OpenGL docs.
    gl.glClearDepthf(1.0f);// OpenGL docs.
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);// OpenGL docs.
    gl.glDepthFunc(GL10.GL_LEQUAL);// OpenGL docs.
    gl.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, // OpenGL docs.
                      GL10.GL_NICEST);

    mygl = gl;
    mygl11 = (GL11) gl;
    int index;
    int counter = 0;
    float zcoord = -7.0f;

  mygl11.glGetFloatv(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, modelview, 0);
  mygl11.glGetFloatv(GL11.GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, projection, 0);
  mygl11.glGetIntegerv(GL11.GL_VIEWPORT, viewport, 0);

    for(int x=0;x<11;x++)
    {
        for(int y =0;y<10;y++)
        {
            index = tilemap1[y][x];
            if(index==0)
            {
                tiles[counter]=new square(x,y,zcoord,0.5f,1.0f,0.0f,0f,"vert");

            }
            if(index==1)
            {
                tiles[counter]=new square(x,y,zcoord,0.5f,0f,1.0f,0f,"vert");

            }
            if(index==2)
            {
                tiles[counter]=new square(x,y,zcoord,0.5f,0.0f,0.0f,1f,"vert");

            }
            counter++;
        }
    }


}

public vector2d getworkcoords(float width,float height)
{
     float[] depth = new float[1];
     float winx = width;
     float winy =viewport[3]-height;
    //vector2d position = new vector2d(0,0);
    int test = GLU.gluUnProject(winx, winy,0.0f, modelview, 0, projection,
            0, viewport, 0, wcoord, 0);

    vector2d v = new vector2d(0,0);
    v.x = wcoord[0];
    v.y = wcoord[1];
    v.z = wcoord[2];
    return v ;
}

public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int w, int h) {
    gl.glViewport(0, 0, w, h);

    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);// OpenGL docs.

    gl.glLoadIdentity();// OpenGL docs.

    GLU.gluPerspective(gl, 45.0f,
                               (float) w / (float) h,
                               0.1f, 100.0f);

    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);// OpenGL docs.

    gl.glLoadIdentity();// OpenGL docs.
}

public float movetox;
public float movetoy;
float currentposx;
float currentposy;
```

public void updatemoveto(float x , float y)
  {
      movetox = x;
      movetoy = y;
  }
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {

```
    gl.glClearColor(mRed, mGreen, mBlue, 1.0f);
    gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    currentposx = mycube.getcenterx();
    currentposy = mycube.getcentery();

    float x = movetox -currentposx;
    float y = movetoy - currentposy;
    double angle = Math.atan2(y, x);
    double mx =.5f*  Math.cos(angle);
    double my = .5f* Math.sin(angle);



    double mmx = mx+ currentposx;
    double mmy = my+ currentposy;

    mycube.updatecube((float)(mmx), (float)(mmy),0);  


    mycube.drawcube(gl);

    for(int i = 0;i<110;i++)
    {

            tiles[i].draw(gl);

    }


}

public void setColor(float r, float g, float b) {
    mRed = r;
    mGreen = g;
    mBlue = b;
}
public void updatecamera(float myx, float myy, float myz)
{

    mygl.glLoadIdentity();// OpenGL docs.
    GLU.gluLookAt(mygl, myx, myy, myz, myx, myy, myz-10, 0, 1, 0);

}


private float mRed;
private float mGreen;
private float mBlue;


int tilemap1[][] = {
        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
        {0,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0},
        {0,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0},
        {0,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0},
        {0,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,0},
        {0,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,0},
        {0,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,0},
        {0,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,0},
        {0,1,1,1,2,2,1,1,1,1,0},
        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
};
square[] tiles = new square[110];

shapemaker mycube = new shapemaker(0,0,0,1);
```

}

I did not include the on create method and the on pause ones.  I would also like advice on designing the code structure because my implementation is far from perfect.

So in short.  I would like help figuring out how to modify the code I made to have a cube move to where i press.  And how you would improve the code

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all,

you don't need to recreate vertices on every moving. It is very complex task and it will low the framerate (FPS). In you code you have model matrix. Usually it is responsible for translating, scaling rotating of your model(mesh, cube in your example). In common case you have to translate the model matrix and then multiple model, projection and view matrixes, you will get the matrix for your device screen. Then by multiplication of vertex postion and this matrix you'll get the right position of vertex.

you can look at this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5550620/the-purpose-of-model-view-projection-matrix)