# ASSIMP Animated Mesh glued to camera, looks 2D

Tags: c++, animation, opengl, assimp

Have been trying to render a MD5 mesh to my games engine but when I do the mesh seems to me glued to the same (follows it around) and looks flat. for an example of the problem, look [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIdeg.png)

AnimatedMesh.cpp:

```
#include "AnimatedMesh.h"

#define POSITION_LOCATION    0
#define TEX_COORD_LOCATION   1
#define NORMAL_LOCATION      2
#define BONE_ID_LOCATION     3
#define BONE_WEIGHT_LOCATION 4

void AnimMesh::VertexBoneData::AddBoneData(unsigned int BoneID, float Weight)
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE_IN_ELEMENTS(IDs); i++) {
        if (Weights[i] == 0.0) {
            IDs[i] = BoneID;
            Weights[i] = Weight;
            return;
        }
    }

    assert(0);
}

AnimMesh::AnimMesh()
{
    m_VAO = 0;
    ZERO_MEM(m_Buffers);
    m_NumBones = 0;
    m_pScene = NULL;
}


AnimMesh::~AnimMesh()
{
    Clear();
}


void AnimMesh::Clear()
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < m_Textures.size(); i++) {
        SAFE_DELETE(m_Textures[i]);
    }

    if (m_Buffers[0] != 0) {
        glDeleteBuffers(ARRAY_SIZE_IN_ELEMENTS(m_Buffers), m_Buffers);
    }

    if (m_VAO != 0) {
        glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &m_VAO);
        m_VAO = 0;
    }
}


bool AnimMesh::LoadAnimMesh(const string& Filename)
{
    Clear();

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &m_VAO);
    glBindVertexArray(m_VAO);

    glGenBuffers(ARRAY_SIZE_IN_ELEMENTS(m_Buffers), m_Buffers);

    bool Ret = false;

    m_pScene = m_Importer.ReadFile(Filename.c_str(), aiProcess_Triangulate | aiProcess_GenSmoothNormals | aiProcess_FlipUVs);

    if (m_pScene) {
        m_GlobalInverseTransform = m_pScene->mRootNode->mTransformation;
        m_GlobalInverseTransform.Inverse();
        Ret = InitFromScene(m_pScene, Filename);
    }
    else {
        printf("Error parsing '%s': '%s'\n", Filename.c_str(), m_Importer.GetErrorString());
    }

    // Make sure the VAO is not changed from the outside
    glBindVertexArray(0);

    return Ret;
}


bool AnimMesh::InitFromScene(const aiScene* pScene, const string& Filename)
{
    m_Entries.resize(pScene->mNumMeshes);
    m_Textures.resize(pScene->mNumMaterials);

    vector<Vector3f> Positions;
    vector<Vector3f> Normals;
    vector<Vector2f> TexCoords;
    vector<VertexBoneData> Bones;
    vector<unsigned int> Indices;

    unsigned int NumVertices = 0;
    unsigned int NumIndices = 0;

    // Count the number of vertices and indices
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < m_Entries.size(); i++) {
        m_Entries[i].MaterialIndex = pScene->mMeshes[i]->mMaterialIndex;
        m_Entries[i].NumIndices = pScene->mMeshes[i]->mNumFaces * 3;
        m_Entries[i].BaseVertex = NumVertices;
        m_Entries[i].BaseIndex = NumIndices;

        NumVertices += pScene->mMeshes[i]->mNumVertices;
        NumIndices += m_Entries[i].NumIndices;
    }

    // Reserve space in the vectors for the vertex attributes and indices
    Positions.reserve(NumVertices);
    Normals.reserve(NumVertices);
    TexCoords.reserve(NumVertices);
    Bones.resize(NumVertices);
    Indices.reserve(NumIndices);

    // Initialize the meshes in the scene one by one
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < m_Entries.size(); i++) {
        const aiMesh* paiMesh = pScene->mMeshes[i];
        InitMesh(i, paiMesh, Positions, Normals, TexCoords, Bones, Indices);
    }

    if (!InitMaterials(pScene, Filename)) {
        return false;
    }

    // Generate and populate the buffers with vertex attributes and the indices
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_Buffers[POS_VB]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Positions[0]) * Positions.size(), &Positions[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(POSITION_LOCATION);
    glVertexAttribPointer(POSITION_LOCATION, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_Buffers[TEXCOORD_VB]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(TexCoords[0]) * TexCoords.size(), &TexCoords[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(TEX_COORD_LOCATION);
    glVertexAttribPointer(TEX_COORD_LOCATION, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_Buffers[NORMAL_VB]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Normals[0]) * Normals.size(), &Normals[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(NORMAL_LOCATION);
    glVertexAttribPointer(NORMAL_LOCATION, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_Buffers[BONE_VB]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Bones[0]) * Bones.size(), &Bones[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(BONE_ID_LOCATION);
    glVertexAttribIPointer(BONE_ID_LOCATION, 4, GL_INT, sizeof(VertexBoneData), (const GLvoid*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(BONE_WEIGHT_LOCATION);
    glVertexAttribPointer(BONE_WEIGHT_LOCATION, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(VertexBoneData), (const GLvoid*)16);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_Buffers[INDEX_BUFFER]);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Indices[0]) * Indices.size(), &Indices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    return GLCheckError();
}


void AnimMesh::InitMesh(unsigned int MeshIndex,
    const aiMesh* paiMesh,
    vector<Vector3f>& Positions,
    vector<Vector3f>& Normals,
    vector<Vector2f>& TexCoords,
    vector<VertexBoneData>& Bones,
    vector<unsigned int>& Indices)
{
    const aiVector3D Zero3D(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    // Populate the vertex attribute vectors
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < paiMesh->mNumVertices; i++) {
        const aiVector3D* pPos = &(paiMesh->mVertices[i]);
        const aiVector3D* pNormal = &(paiMesh->mNormals[i]);
        const aiVector3D* pTexCoord = paiMesh->HasTextureCoords(0) ? &(paiMesh->mTextureCoords[0][i]) : &Zero3D;

        Positions.push_back(Vector3f(pPos->x, pPos->y, pPos->z));
        Normals.push_back(Vector3f(pNormal->x, pNormal->y, pNormal->z));
        TexCoords.push_back(Vector2f(pTexCoord->x, pTexCoord->y));
    }

    LoadBones(MeshIndex, paiMesh, Bones);

    // Populate the index buffer
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < paiMesh->mNumFaces; i++) {
        const aiFace& Face = paiMesh->mFaces[i];
        assert(Face.mNumIndices == 3);
        Indices.push_back(Face.mIndices[0]);
        Indices.push_back(Face.mIndices[1]);
        Indices.push_back(Face.mIndices[2]);
    }
}


void AnimMesh::LoadBones(unsigned int MeshIndex, const aiMesh* pMesh, vector<VertexBoneData>& Bones)
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < pMesh->mNumBones; i++) {
        unsigned int BoneIndex = 0;
        string BoneName(pMesh->mBones[i]->mName.data);

        if (m_BoneMapping.find(BoneName) == m_BoneMapping.end()) {
            // Allocate an index for a new bone
            BoneIndex = m_NumBones;
            m_NumBones++;
            BoneInfo bi;
            m_BoneInfo.push_back(bi);
            m_BoneInfo[BoneIndex].BoneOffset = pMesh->mBones[i]->mOffsetMatrix;
            m_BoneMapping[BoneName] = BoneIndex;
        }
        else {
            BoneIndex = m_BoneMapping[BoneName];
        }

        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < pMesh->mBones[i]->mNumWeights; j++) {
            unsigned int VertexID = m_Entries[MeshIndex].BaseVertex + pMesh->mBones[i]->mWeights[j].mVertexId;
            float Weight = pMesh->mBones[i]->mWeights[j].mWeight;
            Bones[VertexID].AddBoneData(BoneIndex, Weight);
        }
    }
}


bool AnimMesh::InitMaterials(const aiScene* pScene, const string& Filename)
{
    // Extract the directory part from the file name
    string::size_type SlashIndex = Filename.find_last_of("/");
    string Dir;

    if (SlashIndex == string::npos) {
        Dir = ".";
    }
    else if (SlashIndex == 0) {
        Dir = "/";
    }
    else {
        Dir = Filename.substr(0, SlashIndex);
    }

    bool Ret = true;

    // Initialize the materials
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < pScene->mNumMaterials; i++) {
        const aiMaterial* pMaterial = pScene->mMaterials[i];

        m_Textures[i] = NULL;

        if (pMaterial->GetTextureCount(aiTextureType_DIFFUSE) > 0) {
            aiString Path;

            if (pMaterial->GetTexture(aiTextureType_DIFFUSE, 0, &Path, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL) == AI_SUCCESS) {
                string p(Path.data);

                if (p.substr(0, 2) == ".\\") {
                    p = p.substr(2, p.size() - 2);
                }

                string FullPath = Dir + "/" + p;

                m_Textures[i] = new AnimatedTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, FullPath.c_str());

                if (!m_Textures[i]->Load()) {
                    printf("Error loading texture '%s'\n", FullPath.c_str());
                    delete m_Textures[i];
                    m_Textures[i] = NULL;
                    Ret = false;
                }
                else {
                    printf("%d - loaded texture '%s'\n", i, FullPath.c_str());
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return Ret;
}


void AnimMesh::Renderer(float time, glm::mat4 model, glm::mat4 view, glm::mat4 projection, LightDirectional directionalLight, float baseAmbient, glm::vec3 cameraPos, Shader animationShader)
{
    m_pEffect = new Skinning(animationShader, directionalLight, baseAmbient, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    vector<Matrix4f> Transforms;

    BoneTransform(time, Transforms);

    for (GLuint i = 0; i < Transforms.size(); i++)
    {
        m_pEffect->SetBoneTransform(animationShader, i, Transforms[i]);
    }

    m_pEffect->SetEyeWorldPos(animationShader, cameraPos);
    m_pEffect->SetUp(animationShader, model, view, projection);

    glBindVertexArray(m_VAO);

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < m_Entries.size(); i++) {
        const unsigned int MaterialIndex = m_Entries[i].MaterialIndex;

        assert(MaterialIndex < m_Textures.size());

        if (m_Textures[MaterialIndex]) {
            m_Textures[MaterialIndex]->Bind(GL_TEXTURE0);
        }

        glDrawElementsBaseVertex(GL_TRIANGLES,
            m_Entries[i].NumIndices,
            GL_UNSIGNED_INT,
            (void*)(sizeof(unsigned int)* m_Entries[i].BaseIndex),
            m_Entries[i].BaseVertex);
    }

    // Make sure the VAO is not changed from the outside    
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}


unsigned int AnimMesh::FindPosition(float AnimationTime, const aiNodeAnim* pNodeAnim)
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < pNodeAnim->mNumPositionKeys - 1; i++) {
        if (AnimationTime < (float)pNodeAnim->mPositionKeys[i + 1].mTime) {
            return i;
        }
    }

    assert(0);

    return 0;
}


unsigned int AnimMesh::FindRotation(float AnimationTime, const aiNodeAnim* pNodeAnim)
{
    assert(pNodeAnim->mNumRotationKeys > 0);

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < pNodeAnim->mNumRotationKeys - 1; i++) {
        if (AnimationTime < (float)pNodeAnim->mRotationKeys[i + 1].mTime) {
            return i;
        }
    }

    assert(0);

    return 0;
}


unsigned int AnimMesh::FindScaling(float AnimationTime, const aiNodeAnim* pNodeAnim)
{
    assert(pNodeAnim->mNumScalingKeys > 0);

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < pNodeAnim->mNumScalingKeys - 1; i++) {
        if (AnimationTime < (float)pNodeAnim->mScalingKeys[i + 1].mTime) {
            return i;
        }
    }

    assert(0);

    return 0;
}


void AnimMesh::CalcInterpolatedPosition(aiVector3D& Out, float AnimationTime, const aiNodeAnim* pNodeAnim)
{
    if (pNodeAnim->mNumPositionKeys == 1) {
        Out = pNodeAnim->mPositionKeys[0].mValue;
        return;
    }

    unsigned int PositionIndex = FindPosition(AnimationTime, pNodeAnim);
    unsigned int NextPositionIndex = (PositionIndex + 1);
    assert(NextPositionIndex < pNodeAnim->mNumPositionKeys);
    float DeltaTime = (float)(pNodeAnim->mPositionKeys[NextPositionIndex].mTime - pNodeAnim->mPositionKeys[PositionIndex].mTime);
    float Factor = (AnimationTime - (float)pNodeAnim->mPositionKeys[PositionIndex].mTime) / DeltaTime;
    assert(Factor >= 0.0f && Factor <= 1.0f);
    const aiVector3D& Start = pNodeAnim->mPositionKeys[PositionIndex].mValue;
    const aiVector3D& End = pNodeAnim->mPositionKeys[NextPositionIndex].mValue;
    aiVector3D Delta = End - Start;
    Out = Start + Factor * Delta;
}


void AnimMesh::CalcInterpolatedRotation(aiQuaternion& Out, float AnimationTime, const aiNodeAnim* pNodeAnim)
{
    // we need at least two values to interpolate...
    if (pNodeAnim->mNumRotationKeys == 1) {
        Out = pNodeAnim->mRotationKeys[0].mValue;
        return;
    }

    unsigned int RotationIndex = FindRotation(AnimationTime, pNodeAnim);
    unsigned int NextRotationIndex = (RotationIndex + 1);
    assert(NextRotationIndex < pNodeAnim->mNumRotationKeys);
    float DeltaTime = (float)(pNodeAnim->mRotationKeys[NextRotationIndex].mTime - pNodeAnim->mRotationKeys[RotationIndex].mTime);
    float Factor = (AnimationTime - (float)pNodeAnim->mRotationKeys[RotationIndex].mTime) / DeltaTime;
    assert(Factor >= 0.0f && Factor <= 1.0f);
    const aiQuaternion& StartRotationQ = pNodeAnim->mRotationKeys[RotationIndex].mValue;
    const aiQuaternion& EndRotationQ = pNodeAnim->mRotationKeys[NextRotationIndex].mValue;
    aiQuaternion::Interpolate(Out, StartRotationQ, EndRotationQ, Factor);
    Out = Out.Normalize();
}


void AnimMesh::CalcInterpolatedScaling(aiVector3D& Out, float AnimationTime, const aiNodeAnim* pNodeAnim)
{
    if (pNodeAnim->mNumScalingKeys == 1) {
        Out = pNodeAnim->mScalingKeys[0].mValue;
        return;
    }

    unsigned int ScalingIndex = FindScaling(AnimationTime, pNodeAnim);
    unsigned int NextScalingIndex = (ScalingIndex + 1);
    assert(NextScalingIndex < pNodeAnim->mNumScalingKeys);
    float DeltaTime = (float)(pNodeAnim->mScalingKeys[NextScalingIndex].mTime - pNodeAnim->mScalingKeys[ScalingIndex].mTime);
    float Factor = (AnimationTime - (float)pNodeAnim->mScalingKeys[ScalingIndex].mTime) / DeltaTime;
    assert(Factor >= 0.0f && Factor <= 1.0f);
    const aiVector3D& Start = pNodeAnim->mScalingKeys[ScalingIndex].mValue;
    const aiVector3D& End = pNodeAnim->mScalingKeys[NextScalingIndex].mValue;
    aiVector3D Delta = End - Start;
    Out = Start + Factor * Delta;
}


void AnimMesh::ReadNodeHeirarchy(float AnimationTime, const aiNode* pNode, const Matrix4f& ParentTransform)
{
    string NodeName(pNode->mName.data);

    const aiAnimation* pAnimation = m_pScene->mAnimations[0];

    Matrix4f NodeTransformation(pNode->mTransformation);

    const aiNodeAnim* pNodeAnim = FindNodeAnim(pAnimation, NodeName);

    if (pNodeAnim) {
        // Interpolate scaling and generate scaling transformation matrix
        aiVector3D Scaling;
        CalcInterpolatedScaling(Scaling, AnimationTime, pNodeAnim);
        Matrix4f ScalingM;
        ScalingM.InitScaleTransform(Scaling.x, Scaling.y, Scaling.z);

        // Interpolate rotation and generate rotation transformation matrix
        aiQuaternion RotationQ;
        CalcInterpolatedRotation(RotationQ, AnimationTime, pNodeAnim);
        Matrix4f RotationM = Matrix4f(RotationQ.GetMatrix());

        // Interpolate translation and generate translation transformation matrix
        aiVector3D Translation;
        CalcInterpolatedPosition(Translation, AnimationTime, pNodeAnim);
        Matrix4f TranslationM;
        TranslationM.InitTranslationTransform(Translation.x, Translation.y, Translation.z);

        // Combine the above transformations
        NodeTransformation = TranslationM * RotationM * ScalingM;
    }

    Matrix4f GlobalTransformation = ParentTransform * NodeTransformation;

    if (m_BoneMapping.find(NodeName) != m_BoneMapping.end()) {
        unsigned int BoneIndex = m_BoneMapping[NodeName];
        m_BoneInfo[BoneIndex].FinalTransformation = m_GlobalInverseTransform * GlobalTransformation * m_BoneInfo[BoneIndex].BoneOffset;
    }

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < pNode->mNumChildren; i++) {
        ReadNodeHeirarchy(AnimationTime, pNode->mChildren[i], GlobalTransformation);
    }
}


void AnimMesh::BoneTransform(float TimeInSeconds, vector<Matrix4f>& Transforms)
{
    Matrix4f Identity;
    Identity.InitIdentity();

    float TicksPerSecond = (float)(m_pScene->mAnimations[0]->mTicksPerSecond != 0 ? m_pScene->mAnimations[0]->mTicksPerSecond : 25.0f);
    float TimeInTicks = TimeInSeconds * TicksPerSecond;
    float AnimationTime = fmod(TimeInTicks, (float)m_pScene->mAnimations[0]->mDuration);

    ReadNodeHeirarchy(AnimationTime, m_pScene->mRootNode, Identity);

    Transforms.resize(m_NumBones);

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < m_NumBones; i++) {
        Transforms[i] = m_BoneInfo[i].FinalTransformation;
    }
}


const aiNodeAnim* AnimMesh::FindNodeAnim(const aiAnimation* pAnimation, const string NodeName)
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < pAnimation->mNumChannels; i++) {
        const aiNodeAnim* pNodeAnim = pAnimation->mChannels[i];

        if (string(pNodeAnim->mNodeName.data) == NodeName) {
            return pNodeAnim;
        }
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

Skinning.vert:

```
#version 330                                                                                                                                      

layout (location = 0) in vec3 Position;                                           
layout (location = 1) in vec2 TexCoord;                                             
layout (location = 2) in vec3 Normal;                                               
layout (location = 3) in ivec4 BoneIDs;
layout (location = 4) in vec4 Weights;

out vec2 TexCoord0;
out vec3 Normal0;                                                                   
out vec3 WorldPos0;                                                                 

const int MAX_BONES = 100;

uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 projection;
uniform mat4 gBones[MAX_BONES];
uniform mat4 modelInverseTranspose;

void main()
{       
    mat4 BoneTransform = gBones[BoneIDs[0]] * Weights[0];
    BoneTransform += gBones[BoneIDs[1]] * Weights[1];
    BoneTransform += gBones[BoneIDs[2]] * Weights[2];
    BoneTransform += gBones[BoneIDs[3]] * Weights[3];

    vec4 PosL = BoneTransform * vec4(Position, 1.0);
    gl_Position = model * view * projection * PosL;
    TexCoord0 = TexCoord;
    vec4 NormalL = BoneTransform * vec4(Normal, 0.0);
    Normal0 = (modelInverseTranspose * NormalL).xyz;
    WorldPos0 = (model * PosL).xyz;                                
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you might have gotten the matrix multiplication order in the shader wrong. Quote from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5550620/the-purpose-of-model-view-projection-matrix/5554162#5554162):

> Model maps from an object's local coordinate space into world space, view from world space to camera space, projection from camera to screen.

Try changing

```
gl_Position = model * view * projection * PosL;
```

into

```
gl_Position = projection * view * model * PosL;
```

Comment: Haha well it's vanished now